# Transfer string variable between forms

Tags: c#, variables

I'm hoping someone here can help me or point me in the right direction.  I am trying to create an application in C#, I have 2 classes, DB_Connection and MainForm.  DB_Connection is where the connection to the database takes place and MainForm is, well, the main form which contains my interface.

I find myself having a hard time, I'm trying to pass a string from my DB_Connection form to the MainForm all to no success.  What this is supposed to do is grab a query from the db, assign it to the **usr** variable and pass that very variable to MainForm where it will be collected (as an example) by a messagebox, all this with a click of a button.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**DB_Connection findUsrn method:**

```
public void findUsrn()
    {
        try {
            conn.Open();
            if(conn.State.ToString() != "Open")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to the database");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                sql = "SELECT First_Name FROM all_users";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                usr = rdr.GetString(0);
                }
                rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**MainForm BtnSearchClick event:**

```
void BtnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB_Connection frmDB = new DB_Connection();
        string showUsr = frmDB.getString();
        MessageBox.Show(showUsr);
    }
```

Comment: A couple of pieces of advice not directly related to the Q: `conn.Open()` will throw if it cannot open a connection, so no need to check the state right after calling it. If you do decide to check it, no need to convert to a string first - compare it to one of the `ConnectionState` enumeration members, ie. `if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)`. Last, the accepted naming convention for C# is to write the member names in full words with PascalCasing - you don't need to do it, but it will help other people reading your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've removed that part of the code and it does indeed still throw an exception if the database is offline :), but, what do you mean by "members"?  I'm just now retaking C# since I studied it in college and, well, let's just say I left programming/coding in general and are now just retaking the whole subject.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findUsrn` methods is `void`, so it does not return anything. Your code reads the database and puts the result into the local variable `usr`, but then does not do anything with it. Since `usr` is local, it is lost when the method loses scope. You could have the method return a string:

```
public string findUsrn()
```

Then add a return clause (this should be right after the `conn.Close()` statement):

```
return usr;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks driss, I did just what you said and it worked, I was able to pass the string to the MainForm and display it on a DialogBox.